# How can I merge two ddrescue images?

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue

I have two ddrescue images created from contiguous recovery attempts of the same media. The two images are the same size but have complementary data:

```
$ od part-one/ddrescue_image --skip-bytes 227966006774 --read-bytes 32
3242365232766 113056 016517 102014 074371 144073 000000 000000 000000
3242365233006 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
3242365233026
$ od part-two/ddrescue_image --skip-bytes 227966006774 --read-bytes 32
3242365232766 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 124616 163450 064251
3242365233006 074567 134433 012742 022160 044301 054235 140604 020633
3242365233026
```

How can I merge them into a single, complete image?

### Details

- The second image is simply a continuation of the first recovery attempt, à la:

  ```
  $ ddrescue corrupt-partition part-one/ddrescue_image part-one/ddrescue_log
  $ mkdir part-two; cp part-one/ddrescue_log part-two/ddrescue_log
  $ ddrescue corrupt-partition part-two/ddrescue_image part-two/ddrescue_log
  ```
- The second image is almost entirely zeros, but contains 18 KB of recovered data spread across 1847 isolated regions.
- I tried using the technique mentioned [on this mailing list](http://old.nabble.com/Merging-two-images-from-the-same-recovery....-td33002600.html#a33003924),

  ```
  $ ddrescue --domain-logfile=part-two/ddrescue_log part-two/ddrescue_image part-one/ddrescue_image part-one/ddrescue_log


  GNU ddrescue 1.16
  Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
  Initial status (read from logfile)
  rescued:   937286 MB,  errsize:   62976 B,  errors:     122
  Current status
  rescued:   937286 MB,  errsize:   62976 B,  current rate:        0 B/s
     ipos:         0 B,   errors:     122,    average rate:        0 B/s
     opos:         0 B,     time since last successful read:       0 s
  Finished
  ```

  but it doesn't appear to have changed anything.

Answer (score 4):

If you know exactly which region of data you want to copy, you can use `dd`:

```
dd conv=notrunc if=input of=output seek=123456 skip=123456 bs=4k count=128
```

That would copy 128 4k blocks from input to output starting at 123456.

It would be prudent to backup the blocks you are about to overwrite first:

```
dd if=output skip=123456 bs=4k count=128 of=output-backup-bs4k-pos123456
```

If you do NOT know which region of data to copy or are unsure about it, `GNU dd` happens to know `sparse`.

```
dd conv=notrunc,sparse if=input of=output bs=4k
```

That would copy every non-zero 4k input block to output. Use `bs=512` if your blocks are smaller!

Note that there isn't a backup with this method, so you better copy the file if it's important.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this?

```
dd if=part-one/ddrescue_image bs=1 count=227966006784 >result
dd if=part-two/ddrescue_image bs=1 seek=227966006785 >>result
```

The small block size will make this very slow; if you can refactor to use a bigger block size and still land at the correct offset, that should make it a lot faster.

If you can't do that, splitting the operation into more `dd` invocations is probably a goid idea -- read with a large block size such as 65536 to the nearest 64K boundary, then take it slow from there (maybe stepping down to a 1K block size to the nearest 1K boundary before going all the way to individual bytes), then go faster again once you are done with the fine-grained manipulation.

Comment: With the updated information about the scattered regions, this still holds as a proof of concept. Loop across a list of offsets, switching to the second image at the offsets where it contains data you want.

Comment: If you use `iflag=count_bytes oflag=seek_bytes`, then you should be able to set the block size to whatever you want.